# How to find out the difference of time in seconds,hours,day format from current time and timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a time stamp value in my table  that represents the time in which the record generated.

I would like to find out the number of seconds, hours, days before the record generated using MySQL. In other words, how can we find out the difference of time in seconds,hour,day format from current time and time stamp value in MySQL?

Comment: What have you attempted?  For reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I have tried this TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,added_on) , but no result

Comment: Best guess is that your "added_on" column isn't a  `timestamp` type?

Comment: It is a time stamp value I have inserted using the php time() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (SECOND, CURDATE(), your_timestamp_field) from your_table;
```

For more info refer [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: It also worked for timestamp type. please describe your table schema and show some records in table

Answer (score -1):

```
> SELECT A.CALLSIGN,TO_CHAR(A.TIMEOFMSGRCVD ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
> time_tmo,TO_CHAR(b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') time_arrival,
> floor(((b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD-a.TIMEOFMSGRCVD)*24*60*60)/3600)
>            HOURS,
>            floor((((b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD-a.TIMEOFMSGRCVD)*24*60*60) -
>            floor(((b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD-a.TIMEOFMSGRCVD)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)
>            MINUTES,
>            round((((b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD-a.TIMEOFMSGRCVD)*24*60*60) -
>            floor(((b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD-a.TIMEOFMSGRCVD)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600 -
>            (floor((((b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD-a.TIMEOFMSGRCVD)*24*60*60) -
>            floor(((b.TIMEOFMSGRCVD-a.TIMEOFMSGRCVD)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)*60)
> ))
>           SECONDS    FROM (SELECT * FROM ATC.ATCMSG WHERE FLIGHTDATE=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'MMDDYY') AND EVENTTYPE='DES') a, (SELECT
> * FROM ATC.ATCMSG WHERE FLIGHTDATE=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'MMDDYY') AND EVENTTYPE='ARR') b WHERE A.CALLSIGN=B.CALLSIGN ORDER BY 4,5,6;
```